# Completely Disabling WCF Proxy

Tags: wcf, proxy

How can I configure WCF service and client to completely bypass proxy settings configured in IE.
My application works in a LAN and I use both BasicHttp and NetTcp endpoints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the binding configuration set useDefaultWebProxy to false.